# Modify index values as random as ['0', '1'] in tsv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a tsv file which contains 100k records that have sequential index values as,

```
index col1 col2
0     nnn  yyy 
1     nnn  yyy
2     nnn  yyy
3     nnn  yyy
4     nnn  yyy
5     nnn  yyy
.....
99999 nnn  yyy
```

I need to modify the index values to be random as ['0', '1'] like,

```
index col1 col2
0     nnn  yyy 
1     nnn  yyy
1     nnn  yyy
0     nnn  yyy
1     nnn  yyy
0     nnn  yyy
.....
......
1     nnn  yyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
df = df.set_index(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(df)))
```

Or similar solution with assign index:

```
df.index = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(df))
print (df)
  col1 col2
1  nnn  yyy
0  nnn  yyy
1  nnn  yyy
1  nnn  yyy
0  nnn  yyy
0  nnn  yyy
1  nnn  yyy
```